# Open Source App Stor

Tags: open-source, application

I want to manage a kind of private App Store. All users of my company can download apps or software from the Intranet.

Here is a sample of what I want for a private use: http://www.01net.com/telecharger/

Does anyone know a open source service that can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build something like that using Drupal quite easily, customising it however you like.  It's a really simple thing to build, especially if you're not going to be handling payments for apps (though actually that's not too difficult to implement either).

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to use a software that installs automatically? There are a couple software repositories out there that can give your users the choice of software and automatically install that as well. If you're running windows, all this can happen without your users having admin privileges, which generally helps keeping you system save.
I'd go hunting for deployment or software management solutions. WPKG is apretty big one, but doesn't provide the install capability right of the bat.